# Trying to create wpf? kind of things that is similar to window explorer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a wpf application similar to the file explorer in visual studio.

What I have planned is to display the table of contents in a tree format with a treeview and to display a corresponding datagrid when clicking the treeview item.

I'm new to wpf, so I didn't know anything and tried various methods.

In the first method, since the contents of the datagrid that appear when you click on each treeview item should all be different, I created 7 datagrids in the xaml file and tried to control it with the visibility property.

But this method didn't work and it failed.

In the second way, the code is structured like this in the xaml file.
As I expected, clicking on each treeview item loads the corresponding datagrid.

But if I do it the second way, I don't know how to access each element.

So my questions are this.

How to access each cell in below code?

(For example. how to access Name variable?(it's in "TEST1_CLICKED" function)

```
<UserControl x:Class="VSIXProject4.ToolWindow1Control"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
         Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}"
         Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Name="MyToolWindow">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView>
            <TreeViewItem Header="TEST1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="TEST1_ITEM"
                              MouseDoubleClick="TEST1_CLICKED"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="TEST2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="TEST2_ITEM"
                              MouseDoubleClick="TEST2_CLICKED"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="TEST3">
                <TreeViewItem Header="TTEST3_ITEM"
                              MouseDoubleClick="TEST3_CLICKED"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <DataGrid x:Name ="Test_grid" >
            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

---

```
namespace VSIXProject4
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ToolWindow1Control.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ToolWindow1Control : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ToolWindow1Control"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public ToolWindow1Control()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles click on the button by displaying a message box.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The event sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The event args.</param>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1300:SpecifyMessageBoxOptions", Justification = "Sample code")]
        [SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules", "SA1300:ElementMustBeginWithUpperCaseLetter", Justification = "Default event handler naming pattern")]
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, "Invoked '{0}'", this.ToString()),
                "ToolWindow1");
        }

        private void TEST1_CLICKED(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            List<User> users = new List<User>();

            users.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Name = "A1", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });

            users.Add(new User() { Id = 2, Name = "A2", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });

            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "A3", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });

            Test_grid.ItemsSource = users;
        }

        public class User

        {

            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

        }

        public class User2

        {

            public int var_1 { get; set; }

            public string var_2 { get; set; }

            public string var_3 { get; set; }

        }

        private void TEST2_CLICKED(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            List<User2> users2 = new List<User2>();

            users2.Add(new User2() { var_1 = 1, var_2 = "A1", var_3 = "hi" });

            users2.Add(new User2() { var_1 = 2, var_2 = "A2", var_3 = "hello" });

            users2.Add(new User2() { var_1 = 3, var_2 = "A3", var_3 = "world" });

            Test_grid.ItemsSource = users2;
        }

        private void TEST3_CLICKED(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            List<User3> users3 = new List<User3>();

            users3.Add(new User3() { var_4 = 2341, var_5 = "aa", var_6 = "testtest" });

            users3.Add(new User3() { var_4 = 223, var_5 = "A2asd", var_6 = "helaaaalo" });

            users3.Add(new User3() { var_4 = 322, var_5 = "A3ff", var_6 = "worlfsddd" });

            Test_grid.ItemsSource = users3;
        }


        public class User3

        {

            public int var_4 { get; set; }

            public string var_5 { get; set; }

            public string var_6 { get; set; }

        }
    }


}
```

---

- trivial question (you can ignore)
  Can  i display the corresponding datagrid every time when i click on the treeviewitem? (assuming multiple datagrid - in xaml)
  (what i failed)

Comment: not 7datagrids, it;s 3 datagrids

Comment: i jsut want to access "Name" variable when cell is clicked

Comment: i want to get value of name variable when its cell is clicked

Comment: May be you should have a look on [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)